# Since updating to Xcode 11, cannot discard all Git changes

Tags: xcode

Choosing "Discard all changes..." from the Source Control menu has no effect, although I am still able to open Commit dialog, then discard changes individually. Anyone know if this is a bug or if I should be doing something different?

EDIT: I have noticed this happens to me when opening an .xcodeproj, but not when I open an .xcworkspace

Comment: Same issue here, with 11 beta versions, GM as well as the public release.

Comment: I'm surprised that this question isn't getting more views if it's a pervasive problem rather than you and I doing something wrong

Comment: I've noticed that lots of source control related menus do nothing in Xcode 11. it's just very very buggy. Fortunately I never use any of that stuff; I manage my git interactions through Sourcetree, and I recommend that you do the same. Learning to do it from the command line (Terminal) is also a good idea.

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @BerryBlue The issue has seemed to resolved for me now, I'm not sure why or how. I thought I had the issue after upgrading to Xcode 11.1, but you might try that to see if it helps

Comment: In Xcode11.1, "Discard All Changes ..." doesn't work for me too.
I can go back selected files with "Discard Changes in Selected Files ...".

Comment: @BerryBlue actually looks like this is still an issue for me after all

Comment: I have this issue as well - not sure why it isn't working...

Comment: Similar to TakeOne's answer - selecting "Discard Changes in selecting Files "filename" seems to work - but only for undeleting files. I have to close the project and reopen to get this to work to changes in the file other than file deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode. It doesn't seem to fix the issue on files created before the reinstall but all new projects now seem to behave properly.

This also resolved another issue where pushing to GitHub wouldn't work after the initial link and remotes would always show as "loading..."

Comment: What does “uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode” mean?

Comment: You need to delete the app - you can do this by just dragging it into the trash. Go to the App Store and redownload/install it (you may need to reboot your computer before you see it in the app store again).

Comment: Interesting. It's odd that you claim to have fixed this problem just by replacing the app, since so much else is stored else in preferences and caches.